# Tkinter column getting stretched when using .grid geometry

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

In my program, I'm trying to have a big text box sitting below some checkboxes, labels, and spinboxes. However, the size of the textbox is causing the column it is in to expand to a huge proportion. I want the textbox to be big, not the column it it is in.

Here's what the output looks like:

[image]

Here's a picture of what I **want** it to look like:

[image]

I think I need to do something with frames, but whatever I try, I can't get the display to be correct. I've also tried `columnspan` but to no avail.

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.wm_title("My Program")
root.geometry("1000x500")
root.config(bg='lightgray')

def createStrandBox(display):
    var = IntVar(root)
    #var.trace('w', someFunction)
    checkbox = Checkbutton(root, text=display, variable=var, bg='lightgray')   
    return checkbox;

def createSpinbox():
    var = IntVar(root)
    #var.trace('w', someFunction)
    spinbox = Spinbox(root, width=5, values=('0-1', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))  
    return spinbox;

def createToLabel():
    toLabel = Label(bg='lightgray', text='to')
    return toLabel;

def createSeparator():
    separator = Frame(width=2, bd=1, bg='darkgray', relief=SUNKEN)
    return separator;

listeningCheck = Checkbutton(bg='lightgray', text='Listening') #Listening
listeningCheck.grid(row=0, column=0)

lSPLLevels = Label(bg='lightgray', text='SPL Levels') #SPL Levels
lSPLLevels.grid(row=1, column=1)

lStrandCheck1 = createStrandBox('Strand 1') #Strand 1
lStrandCheck1.grid(row=2, column=0)
lStrandCheck2 = createStrandBox('Strand 2') #Strand 2
lStrandCheck2.grid(row=3, column=0)
lStrandCheck3 = createStrandBox('Strand 3') #Strand 3
lStrandCheck3.grid(row=4, column=0)

preview = Label(bg='lightgray', text='Benchmark Preview') #Benchmark Preview
preview.grid(row=6, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=W)

lStrand1Spin1 = createSpinbox() #Spinbox 1
lStrand1Spin1.grid(row=2, column=1)
lStrand1Spin2 = createSpinbox() #Spinbox 2
lStrand1Spin2.grid(row=3, column=1)
lStrand1Spin3 = createSpinbox() #Spinbox 3
lStrand1Spin3.grid(row=4, column=1)

to1 = createToLabel()
to1.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=(0,8)) #to 1
to2 = createToLabel()
to2.grid(row=3, column=2, padx=(0,8)) #to 2
to3 = createToLabel()
to3.grid(row=4, column=2, padx=(0,8)) #to 3

lStrand1Spin4 = createSpinbox() #Spinbox 4
lStrand1Spin4.grid(row=2, column=3)
lStrand1Spin5 = createSpinbox() #Spinbox 5
lStrand1Spin5.grid(row=3, column=3)
lStrand1Spin6 = createSpinbox() #Spinbox 6
lStrand1Spin6.grid(row=4, column=3)

benchmarkPreview = Text(root, height=8, width=50)
benchmarkPreview.grid(row=7, column=0)

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `columnspan` to make the widget span multiple columns.

```
benchmarkPreview.grid(row=7, column=0, columnspan=4)
```

Comment: Oh! Haha! That did it! I wasn't putting a large enough value in the columnspan.